# Is it possible to use the word "become" as replacement for "get"?

Tags: word-usage

Is this valid English?

> Peter **became** a car for his birthday.

Instead of

> Peter **got** a car for his birthday.

Because in German you can say it like this. I am not sure.

Comment: **Definitely not**. _Get_ can sometimes mean _become_, but _become_ never means _get_ in the sense of _acquire_.

Comment: Peter received a car for his birthday; Peter got a car for his birthday.

Comment: The German word "*bekommen*" never means "become". It's just an unfortunate coincidence that the words are similar. By further coincidence, the English verb "get" can mean both.

Answer (score 2):

You can sometimes use *become* as a replacement for *get*, but not in that context.

*Get* has a lot of different uses, and *become* has a number of different uses as well.  Some of these overlap, but others do not.

The most obvious overlap is this meaning of *get*

> 4a : to succeed in becoming : become
> how to *get* clear of all the debts I owe
> - William Shakespeare

[Get Definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get)

In that sentence, you could replace *get* with *become* ("how to become clear of all the debts I owe") and the result would have a virtually identical meaning.  A similar, and probably more common example of this usage describes changes in our emotional state:

*He got mad/sad/confused/excited* means the same thing as, *he became mad/etc.*

Note that *get* tends to be considered less formal, so in certain contexts, it will be safer to use "became mad".

In general, however, *get* does not mean the same thing as *become*.  Here are some of the cases where you **cannot** use *become* in place of *get*:

*Get a car* => gain possession of a car
*Become a car* => transform into the shape of a car

*Get measles* => become infected with measles
*Become measles* => transform into a viral infection (???)

*Get dinner at the restaurant* => go to the restaurant and be served dinner
*Become dinner at the restaurant* => be cooked and served as a meal at a restaurant

Comment: Just to throw a spanner in the works… "That outfit is *so* becoming." ;)